# Upgrading jailbroken iOS 5.1.1 iPhone to (regular) iOS 7.1

Tags: iphone, ios, upgrade

I'm trying to upgrade and the new OS downloaded but everytime I want to install it, I get:

```
Software Update Unavailable

Software Update is not available at this time. Try again later.
```

I read that this means I should try later, but I tried many, many times yesterday and today and it didn't go through. Supposedly the device needs to contact Apple to sign the new OS. I also doubt there is so much traffic to Apple servers now, this update is not that new (8 days old). So I wonder if the message is because of either a jailbreak or because something is wrong (bug) when upgrading for such an old iOS to 7.1.

Comment: Did you try a restore?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you attempting to update OTA on the device? Don't do this — the error message is helping you by preventing you from updating your jailbroken device like this. Instead, restore the device using iTunes to the latest iOS, then restore from backup if you wish.

Comment: That was my comment indeed.

Comment: Yes, OTA. Ok, so that won't work... So I have to do it with iTunes. I have my other iPhone phone synced with iTunes, this one I'm preparing for a friend and I need to do it on my computer. Am I still able to upgrade this phone in this way? I want to backup SMS messages - I think I have to sync for that. What do you recommend?

Comment: @David Make a backup with iTunes normally, then restore the device. Once restored, set up using backup from iTunes and restore the backup.

Comment: Ok, the only thing is that I don't want those SMSes on the phone after I restore, I just want to save them. I found this: http://www.iphone-sms.com/ - it can parse iTunes backup and generate a HTML, PDF or CSV with SMS messages... it's not threaded but I can parse that myself later with a script if need be.